# How to use zxing in c++ project?

Tags: c++, zxing

I'm just started doing things on c++, and I'm interested in barcode reader /writer, so I've chosen zxing for those purpose. Problem is that I don;t know how to use it since it has only `.cpp` and `.h` files. I've used opencv and it was easy to join it to my proj cuz it has .lib files. But ZXing does not.
So, can u please explain me, how to use `.cpp` "libraries" (are they?) in my project (if it isnt hard, do it on `zxing` example please).

Comment: You compile them, just like you would any files you've created yourself

Comment: You probably have to *build* the library yourself it seems. Are there no instructions or tutorials showing how to do that? There's no file named `Makefile` or `CMakeLists.txt` or `configure` or something similar? What does the documentation tells you?

Comment: Yes, there's a little notice about cmake but I have no sense what is it and how to do that. https://github.com/glassechidna/zxing-cpp/blob/master/README.md

Comment: zxing-cpp isn't straight forward or easy to use. Just a heads up that this is a small bump in the road compared to what you're about to face once you figure out how to compile/link it. zbar is easier to use, though I'm not aware of any actively developed forks.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to know if your library needs compilation or no. mostly you need link precompiled libraries to your project and add the path to header files. if it's no, you can simply move your .cpp and .h files to your project directory, in your IDE you add these files to your project and then you use #include with doublequotes. I mean you need to include only header files.

Comment: and what if it's a folder tree with a lot of folders, cpp's and h's inside? should I place em in one fat folder or save ierarchy?

Comment: then you have to add it to your project settings, like in Qt it calls INCLUDEPATH, and you have to set the path to directory containing header files. or just point to the whole library directory. Like if we use boost, and we need boost spirit, so we add INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost/ to the project options and we are ready to use spirit, which compiles in the same pass as the whole executable.

Comment: it would be great if u'l describe it step by step via VS 13 / 15 since I'm a newbie in visual c++

Comment: you can write to my email and we'll see if I can help you, even it's not straightforward. But as far as I know, it's quite simple to add files to project in msvs, you just need to copy it to your project directory and add them to project by clicking "add files", and you're good to go. and yes, why you don't want to switch to QT? just for this library setting up is pretty straightforward. is there any particular reason?